# Running tasks in website background without user request

Tags: php

I would like to find a way (or multiple ones) to allow my website to do tasks in a website background without any user request. For example: website sends a notification to user every 5 hours (adds new record in notifications table), current way I find out is to have a timer with a time on a DB table, but it requires at least one user request to website to work properly. What are the ways to do these background tasks even if none has requested the website?

Comment: You can use a cron task

Comment: @Syscall Thanks! Is this the standard way? Is there any other ways to do it? What about if I need task to run in the background always (it doesn't have any time, simple example: increments number "forever").

Comment: Yes, it's the goal of cron: run tasks. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: @Syscall what about if I want, for example - number that is in a database to be incremented infinite times (there would be no time included) in background, would this solution work too or should I search for something else?

Comment: This solution allows almost everything. You can : run a task every second, or launch a script (PHP for example) which will do a processing to increment your value and which will be executed only once (see also flock). Really a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out.